# Spring boot conversion DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping from xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm upgrading my old Spring app using Spring boot and removing completely xml.

I was able to do all but I'm not sure how translate this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
```

I don't understand if Spring Boot automatically create these beans or if I've to do it manually.

Comment: Ignore them. You shouldn't be even using those classes anymore as they are deprecated. The correct replacement classes are registered already for you.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add following Spring Boot Maven dependencies in Maven XML file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

And then annotate application class with

```
`@SpringBootApplication`
```

and then Spring boot registers all the beans automatically.

Comment: It's not clear if I've to create `@Bean DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` and `@Bean AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` in my `@SpringBootApplication` class or not. Thanks